# Basic java inheritance/arrays. How to use subclass variables with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

In this main method:

```
package practice;

public class PersonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Person[] people = new Person[2];

        people[0] = new Person();
        people[1] = new Employee();

        System.out.println(people[1].job);
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error when I try to use job. Can anyone tell me why, and how it's supposed to be done? Below are the classes I created for the above method:

The Person class:

```
package practice;

public class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
    public Person () {
        this.name = "undefined";
        this.age = 0;
    }
}
```

And the Employee class:

```
package practice;

public class Employee extends Person{
    String job;
    Employee () {
        super();
        this.job = "job";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: because the **compile time** knowledge about that array is: it is an array of **Person** objects.

```
Person[] people = new Person[2];
```

The compiler doesn't care that you decided to put an *Employee* object into one of the array slots.

It is perfectly fine to put Person and Employee objects in such arrays - but when you need Employee specific things, you would do something like:

```
if (people[i] instanceof Employee) {
 System.out.println( ( (Employee) people[i] ). job)
```

Assume you have a bus for *people*. Your idea is that anybody sitting in that bus is an employee. Nope - it is a bus of *people* - you don't know about the individuals sitting there - until you ask them about their nature.

Comment: *Assume you have a bus for people...* makes a lot of difference between this and mine :)

Comment: @davidxxx Well. SO is more on the hobby side of things. After I wrote those answers, I went to clean up some old farmer house, filled a whole container with the trash bags that my spouse "prepared" during the week. That was *work* ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat I joked of course :) That is indeed "work" but by applying OOP  and design patterns, I bet it was a simple formality for you ! Cheater ! ;-p

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly cast the object and change

```
System.out.println(people[1].job);
```

as:

```
System.out.println(((Employee) people[1]).job);
```

Answer (score 1):

> job is member variable of Employee Class not of Person. So you
>   need to cast explicitly into Employee to access it.

```
((Employee) people[1]).job
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. That answers my question. I think the fact that you don't have to cast to methods like that was throwing me.